# Power efficiency in C while loops & polling

Tags: c

I've heard that lets say:

```
 while(1){
    i = !2;
    wait(1);
 }
```

is power efficient. Does this while loop stop at `i != 2` and is therefore not polling? Let's say:

```
while(x == 3){
    if(c == 3){
        x = 4;
    }
    wait(1);
}
```

Does this follow a similar concept or is `i = !2` a procedure that must be met in order to continue the while loop? Would you say that this is just as power efficient? Is the **second example** similar to the first in terms of power efficiency?

An example i've been shown using bad power efficient polling is:

```
while (x == 3) { }
```

Comment: Your first loop will never terminate. Did you mean `while(i){`, possibly? Actually, I don't see how the other two would terminate either, unless `x` or `c` is modified by another thread.

Comment: Why would it stop at `i = !2`? That's just an assignment, it happens immediately. Both loops only stop when they get to `wait(1)`.

Comment: A C compiler does not care about "power". A good optimizing compiler will move the assignment out of the loop in your first example.

Comment: And you're calling `wait()` incorrectly. The argument to the Unix `wait()` function is a pointer to an integer to receive the status of the child process that exits.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937713/is-it-better-to-poll-or-wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing from an efficiency standpoint is that the code doesn't just continually cycle.  In your example, presumably the `wait()` function is returning control to your OS so that it can immediately dispatch another task.

In short, yes, your second example is power efficient as well, assuming `wait()` returns control to the the OS.