# Is it better to poll or wait having multiple stack?

Tags: architecture, threadpool

I have a design question. I am aware of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937713/is-it-better-to-poll-or-wait) but it doesn't answers my question entirely.

We have a Poller application which polls every ~2 seconds to find new set of tasks to execute. In mostly 2 iterations, we get all new tasks to execute for that particular minute. It means that roughly ~28 times, we poll without fetching any new set of tasks.

We aim to reduce the number of times Poller polls. We don't see that in near future, we will have more number of tasks getting added up.

We plan to increase the wait time before Poller polls again. Thinking of 5-10 seconds value. Our Poller application runs across multiple stacks. Tasks to execute per minute differs across stacks. Currently, our Poller sleeps for 1 sec. after every iteration (irrespective of the stack).

My questions:

1. Should we in the first place have wait time/sleep for Poller. If yes, why ? (this question is more from threads/kernel perspective).
2. Is it a good idea to have wait time different for different stacks we have.

Aim to reduce Poller iterations primarily came from design perspective as to why Poller is polling and utilising resources for no reason.

Or, are we over-complicating simple stuff ?

Comment: It is difficult to optimize "abstract" application, for which we know neither OS, nor programming language/libraries, nor code. The only thing we have - is a very **vague description** of that application. What are "multiple stacks" you are talking about? How polling for tasks is performed? Selection of the better technique could depend on may properties of the application, you question doesn't describe even 10% of these properties. So, we could only repeat the question referenced by you: "waiting is usually better, than polling".

Comment: What is issuing the tasks?  Could that entity issue a semaphore unit?